# create a function that will reset my password in the user database, but fails

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So, I'm creating a very simple reset function. One file on the index page is just a html form that looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<form id="reset" action="login/reset.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <label for="reset-email"> Enter your e-mail address here :</label>
            <input type="text" name="SignupEmailAdd" id="login-email" /><br />
            <label for="reset-password"> Enter your new password here :</label> 
            <input type="password" name="SignupPassword" id="reset-password" /><br />

            <input type="submit" id="reset-button" value="Reset my password!" />
            </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The other file that connects the database to the form is called reset.php and it has these function:

```
<? php
session_start(); 

mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
mysql_select_db('testproject');

$SignupEmailAdd = $_POST['SignupEmailAdd']; 
$SignupPassword = $_POST['SignupPassword'];

if($SignupPassword)
    $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET SignupPassword='$SignupPassword' where SignupEmailAdd='$SignupEmailAdd'");

if($sql)
{
    echo 'Congratulations You have successfully changed your password. 
    <br /><a href= "http://www.bla.com/">Click here to go back to the login page.</a>';
}

else
{
        echo 'The email address you've entered does not exist';.
}

?>
```

You see everything works except my else function. It would not show the message "the email address..does not exist" instead it shows "congrats..". What can I do with my else statement? I've also tried this instead of else:

```
<?php
if(!$sql){echo 'The username you entered does not exist';}
?>
```

Comment: Very dangerous code! You're wide open to sql injection attacks!

Comment: The mysql_* API is deprecated, please use mysqli or PDO instead with prepared statements!

Comment: There is not such thing as 'just for school'. Do it right or don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

The function `mysql_query()` returns FALSE if the query is bad, and NOT when the query affects 0 rows. You need to do the following to verify your statement:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows($sql) < 1)
{
    printf("There is no email address error!");
}
```

Also, please consider switching to PDO or MySQLi, which helps with these scenarios.. PLUS! You'd be way less susceptible to injection attacks.

The documentation for `mysql_query()` is here : https://www.php.net/mysql_query , which provides navigation to all those functions.

Answer (score 2):

Although you should really switch to PDO / mysqli and use prepared statements to solve the sql injection problem you have, the problem here is that you should not check for the return value of `mysql_query`. This will return a value that evaluates to `true` as long as there were no errors. If no row was updated, that does not mean that there was an error.

In your case, you would need [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to see if a row was updated or not.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the apostrophe in you've is messing up your code. Use double quotes around it and you should be fine. Also there's a period after your semicolon, and I don't know why.

But as others have mentioned the security issue should be your primary concern.

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous code as markus said.

The first $SQL variable and the last one are not the same.

try:

```
if($SignupPassword)
{
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET SignupPassword='$SignupPassword' where SignupEmailAdd='$SignupEmailAdd'");


if($sql)
...
else
...
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what i've just tried and still does not show the else message

Comment: Ok, did you try the function mysql_affected_rows to check if there was rows modified.

Comment: Because mysql_query for the update statement can return true even if you have not modified row.